# Group spatially different Geoserver layers but use cache of individual layers

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I’m looking for a way to group/aggregate cached GeoServer layers into one layer (not stacking multiple layers on top of each other as done in `Layer Groups`, but combining spatially different layers into one but using the cache from the individual layers).

Let’s have a look at a use case.

We have two GeoServer layers (some raster data, **GWC cache enabled**).
`Layer 1`: spatial extent USA
`Layer 2`: spatial extent Africa

We have two clients:
`Client A` is interested in the USA layer only.
`Client B` is interested in a ‘global’ layer (so USA and Africa together).

*Classic solution:*
Give `Client A` access to `Layer 1`.
Generate for `Client B` a new “global” `Layer 3` (combine data sources USA and Africa in one single tiff or use an image mosaic).

This is a bad solution in my opinion because all layers (`Layer 1`, `Layer 2`, and `Layer 3`) have their own separate caches even though we are using the same data for USA in this example. By doing this we will waste a lot of resources and especially fill our disk pretty quickly because we would have to generate USA map tiles **twice** (`Layer 1` and parts of `Layer 3`).

*Better solution:*
Give `Client A` access to `Layer 1`.
Somehow merge `Layer 1` and `Layer 2` to a new `merged Layer` (which can be called with a single url call).

By splitting up the layers by region we can share the resources (in this case USA data) among `Client A` and `Client B` and save disk space. Clients will also benefit from a shared layer cache as the cache will be filled faster.

I’m aware that this simple use case is not really an issue from the application-side (leaflet,openlayers) where `Client B` can simply load both `Layer 1` and `Layer 2` to generate his “global” layer. By adding more regions this becomes a bit cumbersome and application-side grouping may not be in the hand of the layer provider. To have a single url call would therefore be worthwhile.

To my knowledge, this is not possible at the moment in Geoserver/GeoWebCache.

Am I the only one who thinks that would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is obviously fine.

The only reason implementation is missing, is that nobody decided to [work on it in their spare time](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md), nor anyone has yet [decided to pay](http://geoserver.org/support/) to have it implemented. Maybe you could be the one that does!